# How to detect when autoplay is blocked?

Tags: webrtc, twilio-video, brave-browser

Currently WebRTC fails on Brave browser with "Autoplay was blocked on this page" error.

This error is not particularly visible:

[image]

You can test it with Brave browser where any WebRTC is enabled, e.g. https://test.webrtc.org/.

My app users are reporting this as a bug – since their experience is that the video is just not loading.

What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

https://webrtchacks.com/autoplay-restrictions-and-webrtc/ has quite some (still valid) suggestions. Checking the audiocontexts state as suggested [here](https://github.com/versatica/mediasoup/issues/264#issuecomment-455262127) (linked from a comment) is probably the way to go.

It is rather surprising that brave does this, chrome does allow autoplay when getUserMedia is active.