# Programmable Video doesn't work in iPhone and Brave

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio, webrtc

I'm building an application in Twilio Programmable Video. Chrome and Safari on PC are working well but it's not working on the iPhone. This might be the issue of `preferredVideoCodecs`.

```
const connectOptions = {
  name: id,
  preferredVideoCodecs: ["H264"]
  // added
};

if (previewTracks) {
  connectOptions.tracks = previewTracks;
}

connect(twilioToken, connectOptions).then(
  room => this.roomJoined(room),
  error => {
    console.error(`Unable to connect to Room: ${error.message}`);
  }
);
```

I have added `preferredVideoCodecs` to a call option before users joining a room. But it can't work also. Is this wrong how to add it or code basically? And, Brave browser is not working at all.

Comment: brave seems to be blocking autoplay, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030644/how-to-detect-when-autoplay-is-blocked/61033747#61033747

Comment: I did `<video id="local-screen" autoPlay></video>` but iPhone doesn't support self video.

Comment: iphone needs playinline, see https://github.com/webrtc/samples/pull/926

Comment: Can't work with `playinline`...